# TF26212 Error is coming while saving work item in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have created a workitem type named 'Bug_Tracker', with states & Transtitions well defined. 
When a new bug is created using this workitem, it gets assigned to developer, but when developer marks it as 'Resolved' and assign back to QA, following error comes on saving workitem:-

***"TF26212: Team Foundation Server could not save your changes. There may be problems with the work item type definition. Try again or contact your Team Foundation Server administrator."***

Following is the **XML** for the workitem -

```
<q1:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">
  <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug Tracker">
    DESCRIPTION>Describes a divergence between required and actual behavior, and tracks the work done to correct the defect and verify the correction.</DESCRIPTION>
    <FIELDS>
      FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.Title" name="Title" type="String">
        <REQUIRED />
        <HELPTEXT>Stories affected and how</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.State" name="State" type="String">
        <HELPTEXT>Change on reviewing, fixing or verifying the fix. Active = not yet fixed; Resolved = fix not yet verified; Closed = fix verified.</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.Rev" name="Rev" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.ChangedBy" name="Changed By" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
        <VALIDUSER />
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.SystemInfo" name="System Info" type="HTML">
        <HELPTEXT>Test context, provided automatically by test infrastructure</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps" name="Repro Steps" type="HTML">
        <HELPTEXT>How to see the bug. End by contrasting expected with actual behavior.</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" name="State Change Date" type="DateTime">
        <WHENCHANGED field="System.State">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </WHENCHANGED>
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      /FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate" name="Activated Date" type="DateTime">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      /FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy" name="Activated By" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.Reason" name="Reason" type="String">
        <HELPTEXT>The reason why the bug is in the current state</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy" name="Resolved By" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.AssignedTo" name="Assigned To" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
        <VALIDUSER />
        <HELPTEXT>The person currently working on this bug</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.WorkItemType" name="Work Item Type" type="String" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy" name="Closed By" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" name="Priority" type="Integer">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="1" />
          <LISTITEM value="2" />
          <LISTITEM value="3" />
          <LISTITEM value="4" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="2" />
        <HELPTEXT>Business importance. 1=must fix; 4=unimportant.</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason" name="Resolved Reason" type="String">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="As Designed" />
          <LISTITEM value="Cannot Reproduce" />
          <LISTITEM value="Deferred" />
          <LISTITEM value="Duplicate" />
          <LISTITEM value="Fixed" />
          <LISTITEM value="Obsolete" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <FROZEN />
        <HELPTEXT>The reason why the bug was resolved</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" name="Stack Rank" type="Double">
        <HELPTEXT>Work first on items with lower-valued stack rank. Set in triage.</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" name="Integration Build" type="String">
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="&lt;None&gt;" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES filteritems="excludegroups">
          <GLOBALLIST name="Builds - TranstutorsProjects" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <HELPTEXT>The build in which the bug was fixed</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn" name="Found In" type="String">
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="&lt;None&gt;" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES filteritems="excludegroups">
          <GLOBALLIST name="Builds - TranstutorsProjects" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <HELPTEXT>The build in which the bug was found</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.CreatedDate" name="Created Date" type="DateTime" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.CreatedBy" name="Created By" syncnamechanges="true" type="String" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" name="Severity" type="String">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="1 - Critical" />
          <LISTITEM value="2 - High" />
          <LISTITEM value="3 - Medium" />
          <LISTITEM value="4 - Low" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="3 - Medium" />
        <HELPTEXT>Assessment of the effect of the bug on the project</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate" name="Resolved Date" type="DateTime">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate" name="Closed Date" type="DateTime">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD refname="System.Description" name="Description" type="PlainText" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReopenedDate" name="Reopened Date" type="DateTime">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD refname="System.History" name="History" type="History">
        <HELPTEXT>Discussion thread plus automatic record of changes</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReopenedBy" name="Reopened By" type="String">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD refname="System.RelatedLinkCount" name="Related Link Count" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.IterationPath" name="Iteration Path" type="TreePath">
        <HELPTEXT>The iteration within which this bug will be fixed</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD refname="System.IterationId" name="Iteration ID" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD refname="System.ExternalLinkCount" name="External Link Count" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.TeamProject" name="Team Project" type="String" />
      <FIELD refname="System.HyperLinkCount" name="Hyperlink Count" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD refname="System.AttachedFileCount" name="Attached File Count" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD refname="System.NodeName" name="Node Name" type="String" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.AreaPath" name="Area Path" type="TreePath">
        <HELPTEXT>The area of the product with which this bug is associated</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD reportable="detail" refname="System.RevisedDate" name="Revised Date" type="DateTime" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.ChangedDate" name="Changed Date" type="DateTime" />
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" refname="System.Id" name="ID" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD refname="System.AreaId" name="Area ID" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD refname="System.AuthorizedAs" name="Authorized As" syncnamechanges="true" type="String" />
    </FIELDS>
    <WORKFLOW>
      <STATES>
        <STATE value="Resolved">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="Closed">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <READONLY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="Verified">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="New">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <REQUIRED />
              <VALIDUSER />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
              <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
      </STATES>
      <TRANSITIONS>
        <TRANSITION from="" to="New">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="New Bug" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
              <COPY from="field" field="System.CreatedBy" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="New" to="Resolved">
          <ACTIONS>
            <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" />
          </ACTIONS>
          <REASONS>
            <REASON value="Deferred">
              <FIELDS>
                <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
                  <COPY from="value" value="Deferred" />
                  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                    <LISTITEM value="Deferred" />
                  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
                </FIELD>
              </FIELDS>
            </REASON>
            <REASON value="Duplicate">
              <FIELDS>
                <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
                  <COPY from="value" value="Duplicate" />
                  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                    <LISTITEM value="Duplicate" />
                  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
                </FIELD>
              </FIELDS>
            </REASON>
            <REASON value="As Designed">
              <FIELDS>
                <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
                  <COPY from="value" value="As Designed" />
                  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                    <LISTITEM value="As Designed" />
                  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
                </FIELD>
              </FIELDS>
            </REASON>
            <REASON value="Cannot Reproduce">
              <FIELDS>
                <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
                  <COPY from="value" value="Cannot Reproduce" />
                  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                    <LISTITEM value="Cannot Reproduce" />
                  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
                </FIELD>
              </FIELDS>
            </REASON>
            <REASON value="Obsolete">
              <FIELDS>
                <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
                  <COPY from="value" value="Obsolete" />
                  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                    <LISTITEM value="Obsolete" />
                  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
                </FIELD>
              </FIELDS>
            </REASON>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Fixed">
              <FIELDS>
                <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
                  <COPY from="value" value="Fixed" />
                  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                    <LISTITEM value="Fixed" />
                  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
                </FIELD>
              </FIELDS>
            </DEFAULTREASON>
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
              <COPY from="field" field="System.CreatedBy" />
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
              <READONLY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <READONLY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Fixed" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Resolved" to="Verified">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Fixed" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Fixed" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Verified" to="Resolved">
          <REASONS>
            <REASON value="Reopened" />
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Not fixed" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
              <COPY from="field" field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReopenedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReopenedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Verified" to="Closed">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Verified Fixed" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <READONLY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
              <READONLY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
              <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
              <COPY from="currentuser" />
              <VALIDUSER />
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
      </TRANSITIONS>
    </WORKFLOW>
    <FORM>
      <Layout>
        <Group>
          <Column PercentWidth="100">
            <Control FieldName="System.Title" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;Title:" LabelPosition="Left" />
          </Column>
        </Group>
        <Group>
          <Column PercentWidth="50">
            <Group Label="Status">
              <Column PercentWidth="100">
                <Control FieldName="System.State" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;State:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="System.Reason" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;Reason:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason" Type="FieldControl" Label="Resolved Reason:" LabelPosition="Left" ReadOnly="True" />
                <Control FieldName="System.AssignedTo" Type="FieldControl" Label="Assigned To:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Column>
          <Column PercentWidth="50">
            <Group Label="Classification">
              <Column PercentWidth="100">
                <Control FieldName="System.AreaPath" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="&amp;Area:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="System.IterationPath" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="Ite&amp;ration:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Column>
        </Group>
        <Group>
          <Column PercentWidth="100">
            <Group Label="Planning">
              <Column PercentWidth="33">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" Type="FieldControl" Label="Stack Ran&amp;k:" LabelPosition="Left" NumberFormat="DecimalNumbers" MaxLength="10" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="33">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;Priority:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="33">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" Type="FieldControl" Label="Se&amp;verity:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Column>
        </Group>
        <TabGroup>
          <Tab Label="Details">
            <Group>
              <Column PercentWidth="50">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="Steps to Repro&amp;duce:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" MinimumSize="(100,200)" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="50">
                <Control FieldName="System.History" Type="WorkItemLogControl" Label="&amp;History:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="System Info">
            <Group>
              <Column PercentWidth="50">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;Found in Build:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
              <Column PercentWidth="50">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" Type="FieldControl" Label="In&amp;tegrated in Build:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.SystemInfo" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="System I&amp;nfo:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Test Cases">
            <Control Type="LinksControl" Label="Test &amp;Cases testing this Bug:" LabelPosition="Top" Name="TestedBy">
              <LinksControlOptions>
                <LinkColumns>
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.ID" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.WorkItemType" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.State" />
                  <LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment" />
                </LinkColumns>
                <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter LinkType="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy" FilterOn="forwardname" />
                </WorkItemLinkFilters>
                <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll" />
                <WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="include">
                  <Filter WorkItemType="Test Case" />
                </WorkItemTypeFilters>
              </LinksControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="All Links">
            <Control Type="LinksControl" LabelPosition="Top" Name="GeneralLinks">
              <LinksControlOptions>
                <LinkColumns>
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.ID" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.WorkItemType" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo" />
                  <LinkColumn RefName="System.State" />
                  <LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment" />
                </LinkColumns>
                <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                <WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
              </LinksControlOptions>
            </Control>
          </Tab>
          <Tab Label="Attachments">
            <Control Type="AttachmentsControl" LabelPosition="Top" />
          </Tab>
        </TabGroup>
      </Layout>
    </FORM>
  </WORKITEMTYPE>
</q1:WITD>
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated !